Virtual Raster Builder plugin gives error on mac
I tried different versions of QGIS, different versions of the Virtual Raster Builder plugin, and different versions of mac updates. Doesn't work. I gave it all security privileges and access to all file and downloaded the plugin manually, but it comes up with the same error. I'm currently on macOS 15 Sequoia.
This is what I get:
Couldn't load plugin 'vrtbuilderplugin' due to an error when calling its initGui() method 

AttributeError: type object 'QgsMapLayerProxyModel' has no attribute 'Filters' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 448, in startPlugin
    plugins[packageName].initGui()
  File "/Users/georgipamyatnih/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/vrtbuilderplugin/vrtbuilder/vrtbuilderplugin.py", line 48, in initGui
    from vrtbuilder.widgets import VRTBuilderWidget
  File "/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 892, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Users/georgipamyatnih/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/vrtbuilderplugin/vrtbuilder/widgets.py", line 28, in 
    from .externals.qps.maptools import SpatialExtentMapTool
  File "/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 892, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Users/georgipamyatnih/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/vrtbuilderplugin/vrtbuilder/externals/qps/maptools.py", line 54, in 
    from .utils import *
  File "/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 892, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Users/georgipamyatnih/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/vrtbuilderplugin/vrtbuilder/externals/qps/utils.py", line 2366, in 
    class SelectMapLayersDialog(QgsDialog):
  File "/Users/georgipamyatnih/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/vrtbuilderplugin/vrtbuilder/externals/qps/utils.py", line 2367, in SelectMapLayersDialog
    class LayerDescription(object):
  File "/Users/georgipamyatnih/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/vrtbuilderplugin/vrtbuilder/externals/qps/utils.py", line 2369, in LayerDescription
    def __init__(self, info: str, filters: QgsMapLayerProxyModel.Filters, allowEmptyLayer=False):
AttributeError: type object 'QgsMapLayerProxyModel' has no attribute 'Filters'


Python version: 3.9.5 (default, Sep 10 2021, 16:18:19) [Clang 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.11)] 
QGIS version: 3.34.11-Prizren Prizren, 2904bcec7c9 

Python Path:
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python
/Users/georgipamyatnih/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python
/Users/georgipamyatnih/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyproj-3.2.0-py3.9-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy-1.20.1-py3.9-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas-1.3.3-py3.9-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Fiona-1.8.13.post1-py3.9-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Rtree-0.9.7-py3.9-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.9
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rasterio-1.1.5-py3.9-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.9/site-packages/opencv_contrib_python-4.3.0.36-py3.9-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib-3.3.0-py3.9-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.9/site-packages/GDAL-3.3.2-py3.9-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels-0.11.1-py3.9-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cftime-1.2.1-py3.9-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.9/site-packages/patsy-0.5.1-py3.9.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Pillow-7.2.0-py3.9-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python39.zip
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.9/site-packages/netCDF4-1.5.4-py3.9-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.9/site-packages/geopandas-0.8.1-py3.9.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.9/site-packages
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba-0.50.1-py3.9-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy-1.5.1-py3.9-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg
/Users/georgipamyatnih/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python
/Users/georgipamyatnih/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/vrtbuilderplugin/vrtbuilder


This plugin hasn't been updated for a few years and won't work with QGIS >= 3.34 as there was an API change https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/c76b86e26b33fd25b619ebf641e2c1bb50400308. You could raise an issue on the plugin repo https://bitbucket.org/jakimowb/virtual-raster-builder/src/develop/
